# Rotation and translation from Fundamental Matrix

Tags: camera-calibration

I understand how to extract rotation and translation from the essential matrix.
However, I did not find anything about obtaining the rotation, translation, (and also the calibration matrix) from the fundamental matrix.

Can someone explain to me how to do that?

So given $E =  [t_x] R,$ I know how to extract $[t_x]$ and $R$. But this is in normalized coordinates.

But  from my measured image points I have $F = (K_{2}^{-1})^{T} E K_{1}^{-1}$. So I how to handle the calibration matrices, if $K_{1}$ and $ K_{2}$ is unknown.

Comment: I cannot answer your question as stated.  However, this may help: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html

Comment: This group is a lot stronger on "general" DSP than it is with image processing (my apologies to any lurkers out there).  If you tell us what these various matrices mean, we way be able to struggle through the problem with you, and arrive at an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental matrix involves two sets of projections, through two cameras with two individual intrinsic parameters (calibration) matrices. It can be used in the same way as the essential matrix, to predict movement, provided the intrinsic parameters are previously known.

If your interest is camera calibration, i.e. determination of intrinsic parameters, it can only be achieved via the use of a calibration object  of known form and dimentions. Relations between form and dimentions of the known calibration object and its image on a camera are the necessary elements to estimate the camera´s intrinsic parameters (and pose, if needed).

Please see:
Kurka, P.R.G., Delgado, J.V., Mingoto, C.R. et al. Automatic estimation of camera parameters from a solid calibration box. J Braz. Soc. Mech. Sci. Eng. 35, 93–101 (2013). https://doi.org/10.1007/s40430-013-0013-2